# How to stop seeing untracked folders in pycharm project view?

Tags: pycharm

See attached picture:

[image: r]

`.pytest_cache` are folders that are not code, and are not tracked by git.

They add clutter when I am developing, and are interrupting me.

I would like to stop seeing them. I cannot just delete them, as they will just get auto-generated again.

Can it be done?

Pycharm 2019.3.5 community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it with [scopes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-scopes.html).

- Show options menu (`cmd` + `shift` + `a` and type it)
- Edit scopes
- Create a new one
- You may choose `project` from `packages` dropdown menu to select folder
- Choose `Exclude`/`Exclude Recursively` depending on your files
- Apply

Files/folders will not be shown.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use any of .* plugins with `ignore` feature.

[image]